# springdoc swagger-ui redirect not including hostname

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

When I hit the swagger-ui url I am redirected to a link with the configUrl appended.  But the new url doesn't include the scheme, hostname or port.  Is there a setting that I am missing?

Current properties...

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui
```

initial url: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui

redirect url: swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

Any help will be great.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: if I set the context-path to a value i.e.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/static
```

everything behaves as expected, and I get redirected to:
http:localhost:8080/static/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/static/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

Comment: Using all default properties results in the same malformed URL.

Answer (score 0):

So - I found what my problem was.  Not the reason it caused a problem but changing this does fix my problem...

Somewhere in my properties I was setting:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/
```

this is of course the default behavior, but once that property was removed everything works as expected.